# How to optimize memory with Clistctrl

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using a virtual listview with icon view to display a number of images from a folder in hard disk. All the images are stored in CImageList. There is provision to scale image size in the UI using a scrollbar. For performance sake drawing of each item is done when the NM_CUSTOMDRAW notification comes.

The problem is when there is lots of images, memory taken by the application is too much. And scaling of images is not smooth. Is there any way to reduce the memory usage, say by keeping in memory only images that are being viewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to enable *virtual* mode for your list view. In this mode, the list view control doesn't host any data itself; all it knows is how many rows it has. All data is requested on demand. That makes you (the application) responsible for managing the data it displays, but it also allows you to keep only a subset of the data items in memory at a time.

Instructions for setting this up on a `CListCtrl` are [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58.aspx).

Comment: As i had said in the question, I'm using it in virtual mode. I'm storing all the images in a CImageList which is not attached to the listview. may be i should use some other data type to store the images.

Comment: @Pradeep Keeping the images in an image list means that they will *all* be in memory all the time. That buys you nothing. You need to keep only the ones that you need in memory. When the control tells you it needs different ones, you generate them on demand and throw out the old ones. You can do this using an image list, of course, but a different type of structure would probably be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a CreateBitmap() to create HBitmap solved my memory problem.

Initially i was using CreateDIBitmap() function to create HBitmap. This was storing too much data.
Later i used CreateBitmap() to create my bitmaps in memory. This also stored data in memory, but it was negligible.